# How do we show all the unignored files in a Git repository?

Tags: javascript, git, shell

Another way to frame this question in Git terms is: How do we show all the files present on disk, whether they are in the index or not, that are not ignored?

It seems like there is no straightforward inverse of `git check-ignore` that allows one to handle unusual (but possible) file names with newlines, tabs, &c.

A few Git commands produce null-separated output (with `-z`) that can be used for this task, but the parsing is involved.

With a few Git commands, we can get some null-separated lists of filenames that we can intersect/difference to get the same effect, but this requires fairly sophisticated parsing that's not easy to do (maybe not possible to do?) with Shell, AWK or SED in a portable way.

Comment: I understand your actual question stands in the title, yet the body of your question discusses some technical point about a specific implementation you found. Can you please phrase your complete question in the body of your post ?

Comment: More precisely : are you looking for a way to "list all unignored files" ? or are you looking for assistance in parsing the output of the commands you chose ? If I read the title of your question, the body of your question, and the code you posted as an illustration, I see three different intents ... :)

Comment: What are the three different intents that you see?

Comment: title : you want to list the files that are not ignored ; body : you look for specific flags for awk or sed to parse multiline fields separated with `\0`, and possibly hint that you have filenames with really weird characters in them (`'\n'` ?) ; code : somehow, you also need to not list file which are listed as `--deleted`

Comment: The body of the question provides background information. The title of the question is the question. It's a dense question, for sure. In the body of question, two possible solutions are discussed -- but both require parsing things with `\0` in them. The parsing difficulty relates to needing a list of files. There aren't portable flags for Sed or Awk to parse `\0`.

Comment: So : you want to list files, which are not ignored, and additionally omit files which are still staged but are removed from disk ? (I re-read your code and understood where the `--deleted` kicked in)

Comment: If you have some code to get all the unignored files in the working directory that doesn't depend on parsing in a high-level language, it'd be great to see it.

Comment: doesn't `git ls-files -co` list what you want ? (it will list files that are "present in the index but deleted from disk", but do you have an explicit need to exclude these files ?)

Comment: I think you answered your own question, there: it's obviously not correct. What's the use in processing files that are not present? It leads to errors further down the pipeline.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223098/discussion-between-solidsnack-and-legec).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an attempt in JavaScript:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
/// Run this script in the Git repository. Pass `-z` as the first and
/// only argument in order to process and output null-separated lists.

const execFileSync = require("child_process").execFileSync
const writeSync = require("fs").writeSync
const process = require("process")

const z = process.argv[2] == "-z"
const lsFiles = z ? ["ls-files", "-z"] : ["ls-files"]

const execToArray = (cmd, args) => {
    const data = execFileSync(cmd, args).toString().split(z ? "\0" : "\n")
    data.pop()
    return data
}

const inIndex = execToArray("git", lsFiles)
const notInIndexAndNotIgnored = execToArray("git", [
    ...lsFiles,
    "-o",
    "--exclude-standard",
])

const merged = inIndex.concat(notInIndexAndNotIgnored).sort()
const deleted = new Set(execToArray("git", [...lsFiles, "--deleted"]))

for (let i = 0; i < merged.length; i++) {
    const s = merged[i]
    if (deleted.has(s)) continue
    writeSync(1, s)
    writeSync(1, z ? "\0" : "\n")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`git ls-files --exclude-standard -co` will list all non ignored files (cached + untracked), but would still list a file which is present in the index and deleted from disk.

You can use `xargs ls` to see if the files listed do exist on disk :

```sh
git ls-files --exclude-standard -co | xargs ls -1 2> /dev/null
```

You seem to have to handle weird characters : the following combination of options resulted in the output of file names, one per line :

```sh
git ls-files --exclude-standard -co -z | xargs -0 -L1 ls 2> /dev/null
```

The above can, for example, succesfully be consumed by bash itself :

```sh
... | while read name; do
    echo "===== processing file '$name' :"
    head -10 "$name"   # quote the variable if you pass it as an argument
done
```

Comment: re tested `git ls-files` : I had forgotten it doesn't consider the `.gitignore` rules by default, you have to add the `--exclude-standard` option. Updated my answer.

Comment: This answer doesn't provide a way for further steps in the pipeline to handle unusual filenames and so is incorrect.

Comment: Could you explain what you intend to do with the output ? you seem to want to somehow process it, do you need the full list in one bulk ? or can you process the files one at a time ?

Comment: There is a way to do the read loop which (a) handles all file names without interpreting escape codes and (b) splits on `\0` instead of newline: `read -r -d'' name`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223098/discussion-between-solidsnack-and-legec).

Answer (score 0):

adding to the [answer from LeGEC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64374835/8516483):

When you have soft-links to directories in your repository, you should add `-d` to the `ls` command. Otherwise the output for those soft-links will be multi-line, listing the files in the linked directory.

```bash
git ls-files --exclude-standard -co | xargs ls -1 -d 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34278987)

Answer (score 0):

```
git ls-files --exclude-standard --others
```

if you want to list only the untracked files (files that are not in the index), you can use the `git ls-files --others`